# Visual Studio 2012 RC prevent projects in solution to "auto-bind" to TFS preview

Tags: version-control, tfs, visual-studio-2012

I have a server version of a workspace "c:\project" bound to "$/project" in TFS preview with VS2012 RC.

I have a solution file in "c:\project\default\src\solution.sln" that is bound to "$/project/default/src/solution.sln".

I have some projects in the bound solution that I don't want to include in source control.

I have removed the bindings from "File > Source Control > Advanced > Change Source Control" for the projects i don't want to be source controlled.

Saved and checked-in the changes to the solution file, but everytime I open the solution, it automatically binds the missing projects from source control. In effect the changes I do in "File > Source Control > Advanced > Change Source Control" don't appear to be persisted!

I've tried unbinding and then undoing of the projects and also the other way around with the same effect, where is the binding information persisted?

I've also tried deleting all the .vspscc and have confirmed that each .csproj has nothing on the Scc elements:

```
    <SccProjectName>
</SccProjectName>
<SccLocalPath>
</SccLocalPath>
<SccAuxPath>
</SccAuxPath>
<SccProvider>
</SccProvider>
```

Is there anyway to prevent this autobind from happening? I'm pretty sure I have done this with the previous version of VS and TFS!

Thanks,
P.

Comment: bug reported, follow up here https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/746447/when-opening-a-tfs-bound-solution-included-unbound-projects-are-autobound

Comment: I'm having a SourceSafe problem that looks a lot like what you describe here. Projects set to not being bound in VS2010 are 'rebound' in VS11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks to fixed on July's update.